# Check if a String exists in Postgres JSONB array

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I am looking for a way to find if a string exists in a Postgres column of type "jsonb" that has values like below:

```
id | numbers(jsonb)
1  | ["54954565","16516516","565196212"]
2  | ["195195159","252432","275782872"]
3  | ["54954565","61595161","728278"]
4  | ["245735435","75454","2782"]
```

Eg:

If "16516516" exists in array corresponding to any entry in numbers, I want to get the whole row.

So if I query for "16516516".

The row I get should be:

````
id | numbers
1  | ["54954565","16516516","565196212"]```
````

Answer (score 5, accepted):

that's what the `?` [operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) will do:

```
select *
from the_table
where numbers ? '16516516'
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=5d49b5732031ff3856d0cebbc972f375)

Answer (score 4):

Use the contains operator `@>`

```
SELECT * FROM t 
WHERE numbers @> '["16516516"]'
```

Demo [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=81b193d586cb86c551df575d125e756f):

```
WITH t (id ,numbers) AS (
  VALUES (1,'["54954565","16516516","565196212"]'::jsonb),
         (2,'["195195159","252432","275782872"]'::jsonb),
         (3,'["54954565","61595161","728278"]'::jsonb),
         (4,'["245735435","75454","2782"]'::jsonb)
)
SELECT * 
FROM t WHERE numbers @> '["16516516"]';
 id |                numbers                
----+---------------------------------------
  1 | ["54954565", "16516516", "565196212"]
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks, @jim for this nice answer.
I am searching for two more questions:
1. How to implement contains some for an array. Here, some of elements should contains in jsonb column ["54954565","16516516"]
2. How to implement contains none for an array. Here, none of elements should contains in jsonb column ["54954565","16516516"]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Md.SajedulKarim thanks. I'm afraid I did not understand your question. Could you post a question with some sample data and the expected result? cheers